# How to program an array of Semaphores in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, semaphore

I've looked around and can't seem to find an answer to this.

I'm trying to program an array of 6 semaphores. [1 through 6].

Currently, I have this:

```
protected static Semaphore[] push;
```

Followed by :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
        push[i] = new Semaphore(0);
    }
```

I receive no errors for this :

```
protected static Semaphore mutex; 
mutex = new Semaphore(1);
```

The error I receive is : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

I have a feeling it has to do with not declaring the size of the array, but I'm not positive. Any input appreciated.

Comment: well you didn't initialized the array at all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected static Semaphore[] push;
```

Until you initialize it, a static variable is `null` (which is why you're getting a NullPointerException when you try to access your array).

You need initialize the array:

```
protected static Semaphore[] push = new Semaphore[6];
```

Comment: Thank you, may I ask why I don't need to initialize my mutex Semaphore?

Comment: @Rail24 - You are initializing it with `mutex = new Semaphore(1);`. What's happening with the array is that you're trying to initialize `push[i]` before you initialize `push`. You can't put something in element `i` of the array before the array exists.

Comment: Ah! I understand. Only a couple minutes and I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As Brendan already said, the `Semaphore[] push` is not initialized.

```
Semaphore[] push;            // "push" is null at this point (or not initialized)

push[0] = new Semaphore(0);  // NullPointerException, because you're accessing
                             // an array that's in fact still null

push = new Semaphore[6];     // "push" is now an initialized array

push[0] = new Semaphore(0);  // is now working
```

---

Also, the following works just fine, because you're just assigning an object to a variable:

```
Semaphore mutex;             // "mutex" is not initialized -> null
mutex = new Semaphore(0);    // OK, since you're *assigning* the object
```